# OS X (Mavericks) file sharing: Can only see contents of shared folder, not open files

Tags: macos, finder, permission

I have setup my mac with two admin users, lets call them foo and bar. The user foo has a folder x which contain files and other folders and so on. In system preferences I have enabled file sharing and added "read only" access to the user bar for the folder x. Now, if I am logged in as user bar, I can open the folder x and see its files and folders. However, if I try to open, say, a pdf-file in that folder, I get an error message telling me I do not have permissions. Interestingly, if I copy this file to the desktop (being prompted for admin password), I can open the copy afterwards.

Should not I be able to open all the files as user bar in folder x? Do I have to user more fine-grained access control, like, enabling access on each file?

Comment: Is this problem consistent or intermittent? I've had it intermittently, and disconnecting/reconnecting network connection to the offending Mac fixes it. (Mavericks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid approach to enable access to same folder for two admin users on same computer. Instead, I changed file/folder permissions using chmod, allowing group access (the two admin users belong to the same group).